# Windbg: How to do break-on-write on a kernel data structure?

Tags: debugging, windbg

I'm new to WinDbg, and I wanted to understand if it was possible to do a break-on-write on a kernel data structure (could be a structure or an array), similar to what can be done in gdb ?

Answer (score 2):

Lets say the structure you are interested has a member that you want to break-in when it gets modified. Use:

ba w4 "address of structure + offset to interesting member"

ba = break on access

w4 = writing of anything from the start address
   provided for a length of 4 bytes.

Comment: OP asked about writing on a structure as a whole, not on a member